# procedure myProcedure (text, text) does not exist Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

whenever trying calling any stored procedure in PostgreSQL 11.4 from my java application but getting this issue `procedure pkg$my_procedure(text, text) does not exist`. Note that I'm able to call the SP from DB.

im using PostgreSQL JDBC version 42.2.16

the SP declaration

```
create procedure pkg$my_procedure(i_param_name text, i_param_2 text, INOUT o_object refcursor)
    language plpgsql
as
$$

BEGIN
// myLogic
```

Java code to call the SP

```
        Connection con = null;
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            con = eRestaurantConnection.getConnetion();
            callableStatement = con.prepareCall("call pkg$my_procedure(cast(? as text),cast(? as text),?)");
            callableStatement.setString(1, string1);
            callableStatement.setString(2, string2);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.REF_CURSOR);
            callableStatement.execute();
            rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(3);
            obj = fillObjectInfo(rs);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        } finally {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if(callableStatement!=null)callableStatement.close();
            if(con!=null)con.close();
        }
        return obj;
```

the Exception

```
ERROR: procedure pkg$my_procedure(text, text) does not exist
  Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 6
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: procedure pkg$my_procedure(text, text) does not exist
  Hint: No procedure matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 6
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2553)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2285)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:323)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:473)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:164)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgCallableStatement.executeWithFlags(PgCallableStatement.java:83)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.execute(PgPreparedStatement.java:153)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyCallableStatement.execute(HikariProxyCallableStatement.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.StatementProxyLogic.performQueryExecutionListener(StatementProxyLogic.java:310)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.StatementProxyLogic.access$700(StatementProxyLogic.java:36)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.StatementProxyLogic$1.execute(StatementProxyLogic.java:122)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.listener.MethodExecutionListenerUtils.invoke(MethodExecutionListenerUtils.java:41)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.StatementProxyLogic.invoke(StatementProxyLogic.java:119)
    at net.ttddyy.dsproxy.proxy.jdk.CallableStatementInvocationHandler.invoke(CallableStatementInvocationHandler.java:36)
    ...
```

the call from PostgreSQL

```
do $$
declare
    result refcursor = 'generated_result_cursor';
    rec record;
begin
    open result for call pkg$my_procedure(i_param_name  := 'name', i_param_2 := 'param', o_object := null);
    LOOP
        FETCH from result into rec;
        EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;
        raise notice 're: %',rec;
        EXIT;
    END LOOP;
end
$$;
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: if you want to return a result, use a function. Procedures weren't designed for that

Comment: "Note that I'm able to call the SP from DB"  Please show the example of that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I totally agree but this an old project and we are just migrating from Oracle to PostgreSQL

Comment: @jjanes update the question to include the call from PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created the stored procedure without doublequoting the name, so it is stored in lowercase.

The error message reports a functioname containing an uppercase. Since PG is case sensitive, the stored procedure is not found.

--> use a lower case function name

```
callableStatement = con.prepareCall("call myprocedure(cast(? as text),cast(? as text),?)");
```

Comment: also required to add `callableStatement.setNull(3,  Types.OTHER);` even if this is an output. also, register it as an output

Answer (score 1):

all this point needs to be fixed in the above code. Thanks for @JGH that find the first issue.

1. you need to make sure that the case matches.
2. need to set the all param even if they are used for output. in case there is an output need to set them as null.
3. The last thing to do need to disable the auto-commit.

Java code to call the SP

```
        Connection con = null;
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Object obj = null;
        try {
            con = eRestaurantConnection.getConnetion();
            callableStatement = con.prepareCall("call pkg$my_procedure(cast(? as text),cast(? as text),?)");
            callableStatement.setString(1, string1);
            callableStatement.setString(2, string2);
            callableStatement.setNull(3,  Types.OTHER);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, Types.REF_CURSOR);
            callableStatement.execute();
            rs = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(3);
            obj = fillObjectInfo(rs);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage(), ex);
        } finally {
            if (rs != null)
                rs.close();
            if(callableStatement!=null)callableStatement.close();
            if(con!=null)con.close();
        }
        return obj;
```